# request.getResponse() not returning the actual source from URL

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

I am using the below Code to obtain the source from a web page. But I am not getting the correct output. Its returning some information but when I check the source in the web page using browser, i can see that its very different. (But its giving the correct source for some URLs)

How will I modify the code so that, I can get the same text that i see when i click view source in web browser as the request response?

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim htmlCode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

    MsgBox(htmlCode)
```

Comment: Please share the url

Comment: Its my company network url so it wont work for you, when I access the URL in browser, it gets automatically loged in with my profile. So will it be because of this the code doesnt work? If so how will I simulate the request so that it behaves the same was as the browser does?

Comment: Maybe there is some redirection on the url, check the response in postman or any similar.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser's developer tools to see what happens in the browser?  As far as I know, all of them will let you see all of the http traffic.

Comment: In Browser response I can see the full HTML code.  Is there some way I can replicate the same way browser sends the request from my VB code? That should bring the same source right?